# Making Table header always visible and always centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I know there are many other topics on this. In fact that is how I was able to begin with some sample code someone else had posted, and then I tweeked it to my needs. My problem is that I can't get the table header to always be centered.

```
#TableHeaderFixed {
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    top:0px; 
    width:900px;
    display:none;
}
```

Don't worry about the "display:none" my javascript handles taking it in and out of visibility. I've been trying to read up and see if the "margin" parameter is in conflict with the "top" parameter. Here's the key: I can remove the margin parameter. but I cannot remove the top, or change it to anything else, my javascript depends on it. And yes it NEEDs to be FIXED position. Sucks, but that's what I have to work with. I've already tried using

```
top:0
left:50%
margin-left:-250px
```

The left would center it, then the margin left is to makeup half the width to bring it back, but this doesn't work. Again the margin-left seems to be in conflict with the left, just like I mentioned earlier how top is in conflict with margin, because the margin command never works so it's off centered.

Let me know if you need more details.

**ADDON:**

```
<asp:Table ID="UnitList2" runat="server" />
<asp:Table ID="TableHeaderFixed" runat="server" />
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var tableOffset = $("#UnitList2").offset().top;
   var $header = $("#UnitList2 > thead").clone();
   var $fixedHeader = $("#<%= TableHeaderFixed.ClientID %>").append($header);

   $(window).bind("scroll", function () {
       var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

       if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
           $fixedHeader.show();
       }
       else if (offset < tableOffset) {
           $fixedHeader.hide();
       }
   });
```

.

```
<style>
#TableHeaderFixed {
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    top:0px; 
    width:900px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

So you can see that it's the Javascript which is taking a duplicate of the UnitList2 tables header and then making it visible when you scroll beyond the actual header, and invisible when you scroll back up.

**Server Side styling**

```
        TableHeaderFixed.Width = "900"
        TableHeaderFixed.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-top", "0px")
        TableHeaderFixed.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-left", "auto")
        TableHeaderFixed.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-right", "auto")
        TableHeaderFixed.CellPadding = "2"
        TableHeaderFixed.CellSpacing = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Try these.

http://jsfiddle.net/EdwJv/

Ignore code, go to fiddle

```
<table> 
<colgroup>
<col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
<col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
<col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
</colgroup>
<thead>....</table>
```

CSS for head

```
#hor-minimalist-b th {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #719ECE;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Though this is a good idea, the solution needs to be in the css because this is built with a VB.net table. So it's all information populated on the back by a database. With this there is the ability to add css rules to the table cells and rows, but it won't keep the table header centered. I'll post what the code is because it's a little weird how I did it using two tables, and only one is visible at a time using javascript.

Comment: UPDATED: Solution is in CSS, visit fiddle.

Comment: If by header you mean table header text, i don't see text-align in your css, give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the clarification. I mean table header. I'm trying to get the table header to follow you down the page. The table is centered, and with this css the "fake" or duplicate header (in the second table) shows up left justified.

Comment: FYI: It won't let me post my own answer.Figured it out.

The ASP css styles which were being applied were taking precedence over any inline, or css stylesheet rules.

In the ASP code I was putting in a style to the row of "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" to try to center it. Then when I tried to put inline styles to center it "left:50%; margin-left:-450px;" it was not taking the margin css because of the ASP styles were already applied, or were applied afterwards, giving it precedence.

Thanks for your help 2207792 though, as usual, talking through it gets you thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote in an edit and comment:

> **ANSWER:**
>
> Figured it out.
>
> The ASP css styles which were being applied were taking precedence over any inline, or css stylesheet rules.
>
> In the ASP code I was putting in a style to the row of "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" to try to center it. Then when I tried to put inline styles to center it "left:50%; margin-left:-450px;" it was not taking the margin css because of the ASP styles were already applied, or were applied afterwards, giving it precedence.
>
> Thanks for your help 2207792 though, as usual, talking through it gets you thinking outside the box

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit; converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))